# Exponential of a sum in a non-commutative graded algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

Let $a,b$ be two elements of a graded algebra $A$ such that $\deg(a)=1$, $\deg(b)=0$ and $[a,b]\neq 0$.

I would like to know whether there exits an explicit expression for the degree 1 component
$$\left(e^{a+b}\right)^{(1)}$$
of the exponential $e^{a+b}$.

In other term can we derive from the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula the terms in which $a$ appears once and only once. One can also consider the differential
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}_{|t=0}e^{ta+b}.$$